# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'lstrip'

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe in Pandas that is giving me the error below when I try to strip it of certain characters:

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'lstrip'

I began by removing any missing or null values:

```
df_sample1['counties'].fillna('missing')
```

Inspecting it, I see a lot of unclean data, a mix of actual data (County 1, Count 2...Count n) as well as gibberish ($%ZYC 2).

To clean this further, I ran the following code:

```
df_sample1['counties'] = df_sample1['counties'].map(lambda x: x.lstrip('+%=/-#$;!\(!\&=&:%;').rstrip('1234567890+%=/-#$;!\(!\&=&:%;'))
df_sample1[:10]
```

This generates the 'NoneType' error.
I dug up a little, and in the Pandas documentation, there are some hints about skipping missing values.

```
if df_sample1['counties'] is None:
    pass 
else:
   df_sample1['counties'].map(lambda x: x.lstrip('+%=/-#$;!\(!\&=&:%;').rstrip('1234567890+%=/-#$;!\(!\&=&:%;'))
```

This still generates the NoneType error mentioned above. Could someone point out what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You need to have the `if` inside of your `lambda`.

Comment: If you called fillna like that, it just returns a copy, does not change the original df. Try `df_sample1['counties'].fillna('missing', inplace=True)`

Comment: See the argument `na_action` in [the docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.Series.map.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can "skip" the `None` by checking if `x` is truthy before doing the stripping...

```
df_sample1['counties'].map(lambda x: x and x.lstrip('+%=/-#$;!\(!\&=&:%;').rstrip('1234567890+%=/-#$;!\(!\&=&:%;'))
```

This will probably leave some `None` in the dataframe (in the same places that they were before), but the transform should still work on the strings.

Answer (score 1):

If you are working with text data, why don't you simply first fill None type data with an empty string?

```
df_sample1['counties'].fillna("", inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that your issue is that when you filled your missing values, you didn't do it inplace. This could be addressed by:

```
df_sample1['counties'].fillna('missing', inplace=True)
```

Or, when applying [`pandas.Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html), you could use the argument `na_action` to leave these entries as `None`.

```
df_sample1['counties'] = df_sample1['counties'].map(lambda x: ..., na_action='ignore')
```